# How to filter (and modify) an attachment's ALT property?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF's WYSIWYG field which allow users to place media on it (*Show Media Upload Buttons?* set to *Yes*).

I'm using ACF Pro 5.3.4 on Wordpress 4.5.2 and I'm rendering this field on my templates with the following code:

```
$wysiwyg = apply_filters('the_content', get_field('my_wysiwyg_field_name'));
echo wpautop($wysiwyg);
```

It works, but **the problem** is that images in this WYSIWYG got rendered with its filename (without extension) as `alt` property. Even if I change image's *Title*, *Caption*, *Alt Text* and/or *Description* into the Media Gallery.

I've tried to hook different filters in order to overwrite the `alt` attribute, but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
<?php
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'fix_image_alt_caption', 10);

function fix_image_alt_caption($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
    echo '<!-- fix_image_alt_caption: ' . $id . ' -->';
    $html = preg_replace('/(alt)="[^"]*"\s/', 'alt="Test -> ' . $alt . '" ', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

> Echo is echoing nothing to my HTML, so I guess this hook doesn't work in this context...

Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix my `alt` attribute? Thank you!

Comment: I think do you need update images in WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: It worked @user5200704! Thank you so much! If you want to elaborate an answer based on this comment, you'll get the rep.

Comment: Accept only helpful flag for helpful for others.